# C# linq group By on field and result string?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, expression

how to write dynamic groupby with selectfieldString and resultFieldString?
sample:

```
       public class Customer
    {
        public int Id;
        public string Name;
        public string LastName;
        public decimal Amount;
    }
var lst = new List<Customer>();
        lst.Add(new Customer { Id = 1, Name = "vahid", LastName = "Aghilpour", Amount = 15 });
        lst.Add(new Customer { Id = 1, Name = "hamid", LastName = "rezaei", Amount = 35 });
        lst.Add(new Customer { Id = 1, Name = "vahid", LastName = "Aghilpour", Amount = 15 });


        string[] field = { "Name", "LastName" };
        string aggrigatefield = "Sum(Amount)";

        lst.GroupBy(field).Select(aggrigatefield);---??????????
```

Comment: Your question is rather vague. There is no context and I cannot understand what you are trying to achieve. Please edit your question with more code and try to explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: how to get key with select field to multiple column ---new(Sum(Amount) as SumAmount, Sum(Id) as SumId,Key) give item key but i am new(Sum(Amount) as SumAmount, Sum(Id) as SumId,Name,LastName)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using [dynamic linq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) you should be able to do it.

```
// Remember: using System.Linq.Dynamic;
// The format for the key of the GroupBy is "new(field1,field2)"
// "it" as elementSelector means "the full object"
string field = string.Format("new({0})", string.Join(",", fields));
decimal[] res = lst.GroupBy(field, "it")
                   .Select(aggrigatefield)
                   .Cast<decimal>()
                   .ToArray();
```

Note that if the `Select` is totally dynamic (so it could return a `Sum()`, or a `string` field, or a `decimal` field, or a complex object or a ???), then you can't really do a `Cast<decimal>()`, because you "statically" don't know the type of the returned object. You have to do

```
object[] res = lst.GroupBy(field, "it")
                  .Select(aggrigatefield)
                  .Cast<object>()
                  .ToArray();
```

or

```
dynamic[] res = lst.GroupBy(field, "it")
                  .Select(aggrigatefield)
                  .Cast<dynamic>()
                  .ToArray();
```